# Why is the eventListener not firing for the start button on this app?

Tags: javascript

Connect Four style game im doing from scratch. My first ever little JavaScript project so please go easy on me.

When the "start" button is clicked, the app should then display the game board as well as change the display of the button to "none", but none of the above happens. Im fairly certain i've attached the correct eventListener and function in order to make this happen, as well as the code to display the game board.

I created a class constructor named "Game" to hold the game object and the necessary files for that are attached.

Ive also attached the HTML and CSS.

```js
/** 
 * Listens for click on `#begin-game` and calls startGame() on game object
 */

const game = new Game();

document.getElementById('begin-game').addEventListener('click', function() {
    game.startGame();
    this.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('play-area').style.opacity = '1';
});
```

```css
#begin-game {
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #645a7e;
 border-radius: 8px;
    color: #fff;
 padding: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 0 auto;
 top: 200px;
 z-index: 200;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: none;
    font-family: 'Wendy One', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <title>Four in a Row with Treehouse</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Wendy+One" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
  
  <!-- 
   Start Game Button
   When a player clicks this button, the game will begin
  -->
     <button id = "begin-game">
      Start
     </button>
    
 
  <!-- 
   #game-scene: container for entire play area
   #play-area: container for the board
   .stand-container: the board's vertical support stands
  -->
     <div id = "game-scene">
            <div id = "play-area">
                <div class = "stand-container left">
                    <div class = "stand-leg">
                    </div>
        
                    <div class = "stand-foot">
                    </div>
        
                    <div class = "stand-attachment left">
                    </div>
                </div>


    <!--
     #game-over will eventually display a game over message to the players
    -->
          <div id = "game-over">
          </div>
            
            
    <!--
     #game-board-underlay: container for HTML tokens
    -->
                <div id = "game-board-underlay">
                    <div id = "token" data-column = "0">
                    </div>
                </div>
            
   
    <!-- 
     SVGs were used to create the board and the "holes" for the Spaces
    -->
             <svg id = "game-board">
                    <defs>
      <!--
       #mask: container for Space SVGs 
      -->
                        <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="548" height="472">
                            <rect x = "0" y = "0" height = "472" width = "548" fill = "white">
                        </mask>
                    </defs>
                    
                    <rect id = "board-back" x="0" y="0" width="548" height="472" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity = "1" fill = "#5FCF80"/>
             </svg>
    
    <!-- 
     .stand-container: the board's vertical support stands
    -->
                <div class = "stand-container right">
                    <div class = "stand-leg">
                    </div>
        
                    <div class = "stand-foot">
                    </div>
        
                    <div class = "stand-attachment right">
                    </div>
                </div>
        
                <div style = "clear:both"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
 
  <!-- 
   .table: so the board doesn't look like it's floating
  -->
        <div class = "table">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/Game.js"></script>
<script src = "js/Board.js"></script>
<script src = "js/Space.js"></script>
<script src = "js/Player.js"></script>
<script src = "js/Token.js"></script>
<script src = "js/app.js"></script>
```

```js
class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.board = Board;
        this.players = this.createPlayers;
        this.ready = ready;
    }

    /**
     * Return active player.
     * @return {object} player - The active player.
     */

    get activePlayer(){
        return this.players.find(player => player.active);
    }

    /** 
 * Creates two player objects
 * @return  {Array}    An array of two Player objects.
 */

    createPlayers() {
        const players = [new Player('Player 1', 1, '#e15258', true),
                        new Player('Player 2', 2, '#e59a13')]
        return players;
    }

    /** 
 * Initializes game. 
 */
startGame(){
    this.board.drawHTMLBoard();
    this.activePlayer.activeToken.drawHTMLToken();
    this.ready = true;
}

}
```

Comment: when is the js code run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your eventListner is getting triggered. See your snippet focusing on the listner https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-0gwxj

Be sure the rest of the imports in your HTML file load properly and they are not throwing errors.

Comment: rookie error on my part. the source files were actually being saved in the cloud but the compiler was looking for them locally. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run it by adding board and ready to constructor as they were left undefined.

```
class Game {
    constructor(Board, ready) {
        this.board = Board;
        this.players = this.createPlayers;
        this.ready = ready;
    }

    /**
     * Return active player.
     * @return {object} player - The active player.
     */

    get activePlayer(){
        return this.players.find(player => player.active);
    }

    /** 
 * Creates two player objects
 * @return  {Array}    An array of two Player objects.
 */

    createPlayers() {
        const players = [new Player('Player 1', 1, '#e15258', true),
                        new Player('Player 2', 2, '#e59a13')]
        return players;
    }

    /** 
 * Initializes game. 
 */
startGame(){
        alert('here');
    this.board.drawHTMLBoard();
    this.activePlayer.activeToken.drawHTMLToken();
    this.ready = true;
}

}

/** 
 * Listens for click on `#begin-game` and calls startGame() on game object
 */

const game = new Game("","");

document.getElementById('begin-game').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('here');
    game.startGame();
    this.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('play-area').style.opacity = '1';
});
```

Comment: perhaps im missing something but i made the changes you've outlined here and still getting nothing in return. Debugger says "game is not defined"

Comment: which means Game file not imported.